# Should I move my custom commands from the end of ~/.profile to the end of ~/.zprofile when I install zsh and oh-my-zsh?

Tags: shell-script, zsh

I am a new user of `zsh` and `oh-my-zsh`.

Before I installed `zsh` and `oh-my-zsh` I configured my `~/.profile` to start some programs automatically.  For example, my `~/.profile` would start `guake` after a 4 second delay:

```
`sleep 4; guake&`&
```

Now that I have installed `zsh`, will the custom commands that I have added to my `~/.profile` have the same effect if I move them to `~/.zprofile`?

Adding commands to `~/.zshrc` seems to have a similar effect to adding them to `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: The answer to this question is that you should not install oh my anything.

Comment: // , But right on their website, it says, "Once installed, your terminal prompt will become the talk of the town or your money back!" 

How can I ignore such guarantees, @mikeserv?

Comment: With haughty aplomb.

Comment: I agree with @mikeserv. I have yet to ever have a good experience with oh-my-zsh. Handcrafting my ``.zshrc`` has been far better.

Comment: @HalosGhost enter Antigen/Zgen

Answer (score 0):

Look here:

> Commands are first read from /etc/zshenv; this cannot be overridden. Subsequent behaviour is modified by the RCS and GLOBAL_RCS options; the former affects all startup files, while the second only affects global startup files (those shown here with an path starting with a /). If one of the options is unset at any point, any subsequent startup file(s) of the corresponding type will not be read. It is also possible for a file in $ZDOTDIR to re-enable GLOBAL_RCS. Both RCS and GLOBAL_RCS are set by default.
>
> **Commands are then read from $ZDOTDIR/.zshenv. If the shell is a login shell, commands are read from /etc/zprofile and then $ZDOTDIR/.zprofile. Then, if the shell is interactive, commands are read from /etc/zshrc and then $ZDOTDIR/.zshrc. Finally, if the shell is a login shell, /etc/zlogin and $ZDOTDIR/.zlogin are read**.

in [the manual](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Files.html) (emphasis mine), and here:

> '.zshenv' is sourced on all invocations of the shell, unless the -f option is set. It should contain commands to set the command search path, plus other important environment variables. '.zshenv' should not contain commands that produce output or assume the shell is attached to a tty.
>
> '.zshrc' is sourced in interactive shells. It should contain commands to set up aliases, functions, options, key bindings, etc.
>
> **'.zlogin' is sourced in login shells. It should contain commands that should be executed only in login shells. '.zlogout' is sourced when login shells exit. '.zprofile' is similar to '.zlogin', except that it is sourced before '.zshrc'. '.zprofile' is meant as an alternative to '.zlogin' for ksh fans; the two are not intended to be used together, although this could certainly be done if desired.** '.zlogin' is not the place for alias definitions, options, environment variable settings, etc.; as a general rule, it should not change the shell environment at all. Rather, it should be used to set the terminal type and run a series of external commands (fortune, msgs, etc).

from [An Introduction to Zsh](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Intro/intro_3.html) (emphasis mine).

So the answer is, probably, depending on what you need the commands to do.